# I am able to log in to google account but not able to get the user access token

Tags: iphone, google-plus, access-token

I am login into google account but not able to get the login user access token. In the GTMOAuth2Authentication.m file its still not giving me the user access token.
Any sample code will help a lot..

Answer (score 1):

to get google plus login data on button click..

```
-(IBAction)googleLogin:(id)sender{
  GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
  [GPPSignInButton class];
  signIn.clientID = kClientID;
  signIn.delegate = self;
  signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = TRUE;
  signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID=TRUE;
  signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
               @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
               nil];

 [signIn authenticate];
 [signIn trySilentAuthentication];
```

}

and delegate method to get information

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error: (NSError *) error
   {
      NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);

      if (error) {
         // Do some error handling here.
      } else {
          NSLog(@"email:%@",auth.userEmail);
          NSLog(@"userData:%@",auth.userData);
           NSLog(@"user id is---%@",auth.userID);
           self.str=auth.accessToken;
           NSLog(@"my string value is---->%@",str);

///////////// for getting full profile inforamation///////////


        GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] autorelease];
        plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
        [plusService setAuthorizer: auth];
         GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];

          [plusService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLPlusPerson *person, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
    GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
  }
       else {
    // Get an array of people from GTLPlusPeopleFeed
         [person retain];
       NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@", person.displayName,person.gender,person.image.url,person.relationshipStatus,person.name.familyName,person.name.givenName];
         NSLog(@"description:%@", description);

  }
}];
```

}
}

Comment: here kclientID is your google api key which you get when you register your app on developer.google.com